# Error in Linq, Count()

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying write this sql query to Linq:

**SQL:**

```
select c.course_name, count(s.s_name) as studenti from course c 
join study_group g on g.course_id=c.id 
join student s on s.study_group_id=g.id 
group by c.course_name;
```

**Linq:**

```
var countStudents = (from s in ado.student //on g.id equals s.study_group_id
                     join g in ado.study_group on s.study_group_id equals g.id
                     join c in ado.course on g.course_id equals c.id
                     group s by c.course_name into cn
                     let count = cn.Count(co => co.s_name)
                     select new 
                     {
                        c.course_name
                        course_name = cn.Key
                     });
```

and still I have an error at `co => co.s_name`

Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'`

Know anybody how to fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) - `Count` is expecting a `Func<T,bool>`, and wants to count the results which return true. There's no overload to count distinct strings as (I think) you are trying to do here. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it either, sorry.

Comment: or, if anybody know another way get this SQL to Linq ??, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL `COUNT(column)` aggregate function only counts not null values. The equivalent in LINQ would be to replace the line:

```
let count = cn.Count(co => co.s_name)
```

by

```
let count = cn.Count(co => co.s_name != null)
```

Of course, no guarantees on the generated SQL here. Either way, it is strange that a student's name may be null, though I have no intention of discussing your model.

*Note*
You won't be able to retrieve the desired count unless you `select` it in your code. Also, do check if students' names can be null, because in case they can't, just a `cn.Count()` would suffice.

Comment: @user1726810, please do check your SQL, though. You should probably want to group by *courseid* instead of the course's name (unless they are unique identifiers of your courses). Also, I have a strong feeling that students' names can't be null, in which case a simple `cn.Count()` would suffice. Do check your model so that your SQL is clear and concise; it could help you avoid mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the `Count` clause in your LINQ statement?  Just use a `.Count()` extension method on the `IEnumerable` that's returned from your query to get the count.

```
var count = countStudents.Count();
```

Comment: I have to use variable, because I need Count of every c.course_name,
just edit